# LDAP Ambiguous Name Resolution (ANR) equivalent on Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm building a tool that can target both on-prem Active Directory and Azure AD that, amongst other things, searches `user` objects.

For on-prem, I can do an LDAP search using ambiguous name resolution with a query like this:

```
(anr=searchstring*)
```

Is there an equivalent filter string for the Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after some trial & error, I managed to replicate Ambiguous Name Resolution using the filter syntax. It's not an exact match because not all attributes are searchable, but I guess it will have to do.

Here's my helper class I created for the job.

```
public static class QueryHelper
{
    public static string GenerateAnrFilter(string query)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
            return query;
        var tokens = query.Split(' ');
        var filterClauses = new List<string>();
        if (tokens.Count() > 1)
        {
            var otherTokens = string.Join(" ", tokens.Skip(1));
            string nameFilter1 = $"({generateFilterClause(tokens[0], "givenName")} and {generateFilterClause(otherTokens, "surname")})";
            filterClauses.Add(nameFilter1);
            string nameFilter2 = $"({generateFilterClause(otherTokens, "givenName")} and {generateFilterClause(tokens[0], "surname")})";
            filterClauses.Add(nameFilter2);
            filterClauses.Add(generateFilterClause(query, "displayName"));
            //filterClauses.Add(generateFilterClause(query, "officeLocation")); // not supported for filter
            filterClauses.Add(generateMultiValueFilterClause(query, "proxyAddresses"));
            filterClauses.Add(generateFilterClause(query, "userPrincipalName"));
            //filterClauses.Add(generateFilterClause(query, "onPremisesSamAccountName")); // not supported for filter
            filterClauses.Add(generateFilterClause(query, "mail"));
            filterClauses.Add(generateFilterClause(query, "mailNickName"));
        }
        else
        {
            filterClauses.Add(generateFilterClause(query, "displayName"));
            filterClauses.Add(generateFilterClause(query, "givenName"));
            filterClauses.Add(generateFilterClause(query, "surname"));
            //filterClauses.Add(generateFilterClause(query, "officeLocation")); // not supported for filter
            filterClauses.Add(generateMultiValueFilterClause(query, "proxyAddresses"));
            filterClauses.Add(generateFilterClause(query, "userPrincipalName"));
            //filterClauses.Add(generateFilterClause(query, "onPremisesSamAccountName")); // not suported for filter
            filterClauses.Add(generateFilterClause(query, "mail"));
            filterClauses.Add(generateFilterClause(query, "mailNickName"));
        }
        var fullQuery = string.Join(" or ", filterClauses);
        return fullQuery;
    }

    private static string generateMultiValueFilterClause(string query, string attributeName)
    {
        return $"{attributeName}/any(a:startswith(a,'{query}'))";
    }

    private static string generateFilterClause(string query, string attributeName)
    {
        return $"startsWith({attributeName},'{query}')";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to `{string}*` is the [OData](https://www.odata.org/) `startsWith({property},'{string}')` [Filter parmeter](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startsWith(displayName,'Adele')):

```
/v1.0/users?$filter=startsWith(displayName,'Adele')
```

Note that the Microsoft Graph currently only supports a [subset of OData query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?toc=.%2Fref%2Ftoc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0#odata-system-query-options), particularly when it comes to AAD filters:

> The following `$filter` operators are **not** supported for Azure AD resources: `ne`, `gt`, `ge`, `lt`, `le`, and `not`.

Also, Microsoft Graph does not support `contains` or `endswith` string functions in *any* workload.

*You can try test your queries this using [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=users?$filter=startsWith(displayName,'Adele')&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com).*

Comment: So, to put it in my own words, there's no Ambiguous Name Resolution search in Microsoft graph, instead you have to build the filter on your own. Couldn't there be an URL length problem? Looking at what attributes a LDAP Ambiguous Name Resolution search goes through on Active Directory, there's 13 attributes. That makes for a long query URL, especially if you then also want to select certain properties. Is there an official query string limit for Microsoft Graph?